# Is there any constraint on the size of Vastu-purusha for Vastu Shanti?

Tags: vastu-shastra

I was told that the Vastu Purusha should be of at least 3 grams of gold.
I would like to know if that's true/written anywhere.
To me, it's size shouldn't really matter. But I was told so by our priest.

Comment: Vastu purusha is symbolic. Its not mandatory to give in gold and that too specific size. You may talk with other priest

Comment: Yes.. That is what I was thinking exactly.. thanks.